# Fancybox working in .html but not in .xml

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I am working on a project for university and want to use Fancybox on a XHTML page which is in .xml format.

The trouble now is, that using a .html file is working, but using almost the same code in a .xml file is not working at all. Means the path of fancybox is correct.

This is the .xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html
  SYSTEM "about:legacy-compat">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>fancybox testing</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.js?v=2.1.3"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.3" media="screen" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            });
        </script>   
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <a class="fancybox" href="1.png">image</a>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This code in a .html file is working.
Any idea why? I need fancybox in the .xml :-/

Thank you

Comment: Are you sure you don't want .xHtml? .xml won't be interpreted as an HTML webpage in most browsers I think.

Comment: What do you see when you visit this page as .xml file?

Comment: "I need fancybox in the .xml" You cannot

Comment: Name your file .html and you are good.

Comment: It's not possible / es tut mir leid, aber es ist einfach nicht möglich / Ce n' est pas possible! / Non è possibile / No se puede !! ... you may pull a xml file inside fancybox though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that XML is something different than XHTML.

XML is eXtendable Markup Language (you can invent your own tags), while XHTML is 'perfect' HTML. If you use the .XML extension your server sends a different set of headers to your browser (telling the browser it is an XML page, and the browser thus won't display this as an HTML webpage), than when you use the .XHTML extension (headers telling your browser it is 'superclean' HTML).

If you can't change the file extension you should change the headers sent by the server if this file gets requested. Otherwise this won't work, because the browser doesn't know what to do with the XML otherwise.